# Sort stacked graphs in the y axis

Tags: amazon-web-services, bar-chart, stacked-chart, amazon-quicksight

I'm using a stacked graph in AWS quicksight and I need to be able to sort by `Cost` vertically. The only option I see is to sort by `Cost` horizontally making the dates appear out of order. By default it's sorted A-Z vertically.

How can I get the larger costs at the bottom and all the tiny costs at the top of the graph?

**[image: .]**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No sorry I never did. Might be worth an AWS support ticket as this ordering makes all the colours look ugly which is important for management xD Although if you order in this way items would have a different colour per month potentially causing other issues. Not sure on the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a number in front of each "Color" (SQL column names) in the order that you need?. That will sort them accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).